# Add input to the media uploader and pass its value to each uploaded file

Tags: media

Suppose I have a select element containing a list of my custom taxonomies or terms, I need to add it to the media library uploader so that the admin can choose the custom taxonomy to which he wants to add this bulk of files once these files are uploaded successfully, and each file has its own post.

I'm wondering if I can use the `add_attachment` hook and apply the selected taxonomy and the term IDs with `wp_set_object_terms()`.

Another thought is to attach a meta data for each uploaded video/attachment, this meta data is the term of the attachment, then I'll develop a function which the user will call to generate a post for each attachment containing that meta data.